# This day in history I

Tags: riddle, history

**THIS DAY IN HISTORY is a series of puzzles I intend to create in which I choose an event a certain amount of years ago. I need you to figure the event and tell me how many years ago it happened**

From a great maker of bikes
Comes something the government likes
Took on this day
And now there's a lot in the place
Of which it originates

**I will release the answer when the next one is released**

Comment: Does double-meaninged count as cryptic?

Comment: yep, but only if it is used correctly. see Deusovi's Cryptic Clue Guide post on the site for more details!

Comment: Will you be specifying the date going forward? I don’t think the right answer occurred on July 27...

Comment: I know. This first one was a research mistake. However, I will

Comment: Please read the tag summaries for tags you're using if you're not sure they apply—and particularly if someone has already called one into question.  This is most definitely *not* a [tag:cryptic-clues] puzzle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it

> The Wright Brothers making the first successful plane?

From a great maker of bikes

> The Wright Brothers built the first working plane, but before that they made bikes

Comes something the government likes

> The government uses planes a lot

Took on this day

> Planes are used very often these days

And now there's a lot in the place
Of which it originates

> The first plane was made in North Carolina, and there are a lot of planes in North Carolina now

If so, it happened in

> 1903

So it happened around

> 116 years ago