# This day in history II

Tags: riddle, history

**[This day in history I](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86601/this-day-in-history-i)** **was correctly answered by PotatoLatte. I will describe an event from a certain number of years ago that happened today (28/07). I would like you to tell me both he event and the amount of years ago it happened.**

A glove, these dark people hold
They did something - stupid or bold?
One split to two
Thousands of miles from those who
Were affected by this awful event
Only 2 million minutes would last
Before this disaster was in the past

Comment: If you mean that it happened *this* day then can I suggest you put the date in the question? Most of us don't know what time zone you're in, to know what day it is for you. Also, it saves people who come later to this page from having to check and see when you posted this.

Comment: @msh210; the date gets stamped into the question data.

Comment: @JonMarkPerry Yes, but if somebody in the US posted a riddle at 10pm on Sunday, they presumably mean "today" as 28/07  (well, 07/28 but that's another kettle of fish). But someone in Europe seeing that riddle just after it was posted would take "today" as being 29/07. So it's definitely worth including the intended data

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Could be

> Start of **World War I** - Started 28.07.1914 (105 years ago) and it lasted 2.2 million minutes.
>  The Europe split to two: the Triple Entente—consisting of France, Russia, and Britain—and the Triple Alliance of Germany, Austria-Hungary, and Italy.

Comment: That's exactly the answer I thought about ,rot13(Rira gubhtu gur cneg sbe 2 va zl bcvavba vf Nhfgevn-Uhatnel, juvpu unf whfg qrpynerq jne ba Freovn naq gung vf jung gevttrerq gur jne) but anyway give you +1 :)

Comment: What's the glove bit about?

Comment: @JMP the Black Hand were the extremist group who shot him. The holders of the dark hand. I know it's not the greatest riddle ever written :)