# This day in history III

Tags: riddle, history

**The correct answer to [This day in history II](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/86629/this-day-in-history-ii?noredirect=1#comment251927_86629) was found by Jan Ivan with credit to Tahel.**

**A certain amount of years ago on this day (29/07), something happened. What is it and how many years ago did it happen?**

Saint Snowman
And son of Harold
A first for the monarchs
Who died a bloody death

Comment: What are the odds of 3 people replying within 2 minutes of each other, roughly 20 minutes after the question is asked?

Comment: TBQH I'm no historian, everything boils down to my excellent Google searching skills.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> [Olaf II of Norway](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olaf_II_of_Norway) a.k.a. St. Olaf, son of [Harald Grenske](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harald_Grenske) was killed in the [Battle of Stiklestad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Stiklestad).

Comment: Come on, we answered almost at that moment and the same answer, we have telepathy ..., you deserve +1 just for that ...

Comment: @Tahel - 3 minutes isn't exactly a _moment_ ;)

Comment: Dear @INTERESTING You are right, but what will I do, for me the browser takes time to refresh, (much more than 3 minutes ),I've seen the answer of Mordechai only after I've written mine and I had a disappointing erase it (it takes me a long time to write any answer because I do not know English at a high level-English is not my mother tongue).

Answer (score 8):

the answer is:

> Battle of Stiklestad-Death of King Olaf II in 1030 (989 years ago)

Saint Snowman

> **Saint** - the Roman Catholic Church declared Olaf a saint in 1164,**Snowman**-Olaf is the snowman in "frozen"

And son of Harold

> his father was Harald Grenske

A first for the monarchs

> The first king of Norway was his great-great-grandfather

Who died a bloody death

> in Battle of Stiklestad

Comment: Better answer, to be honest; I missed (and still miss) the snowman part. +1

Comment: @Mordechai - Olaf is a snowman in the movie _Frozen_ so that’s probably the reference here.

Comment: Well done to both of you +1 each. I can't tell who answered before who but it looks as if it was amazingly close. I'm going to give Tahel the correct answer mark as he explained it in more detail. But both amazing. I thought this would be way more obscure but both found it instantaneously

Comment: @WilliamPennanti: if you hover over the time “Answered x ago” on PC, then you’ll be able to see a timestamp in UTC for each answer that you receive. (Or you can sort answers oldest to newest!) I believe Mordechai was the first answerer by a couple of minutes, but as always it’s your choice as to who answers best!